# Android GCM Client exception

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I'm recently started to learn about Android GCM. I am trying the GCM Client sample given in Android Developer at [here](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/client.html), and when i tried to click the send button in the MainActivity, it gave me some exception as below:

```
09-06 00:16:41.480: E/AndroidRuntime(1246): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-06 00:16:41.480: E/AndroidRuntime(1246): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate receiver com.google.android.gcm.demo.app.GcmBroadcastReceiver: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.android.gcm.demo.app.GcmBroadcastReceiver" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.google.android.gcm.demo.app-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.google.android.gcm.demo.app-1, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
09-06 00:16:41.480: E/AndroidRuntime(1246):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2405)
09-06 00:16:41.480: E/AndroidRuntime(1246):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:141)
09-06 00:16:41.480: E/AndroidRuntime(1246):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1332)
09-06 00:16:41.480: E/AndroidRuntime(1246):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-06 00:16:41.480: E/AndroidRuntime(1246):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
09-06 00:16:41.480: E/AndroidRuntime(1246):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
09-06 00:16:41.480: E/AndroidRuntime(1246):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-06 00:16:41.480: E/AndroidRuntime(1246):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
09-06 00:16:41.480: E/AndroidRuntime(1246):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
09-06 00:16:41.480: E/AndroidRuntime(1246):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
09-06 00:16:41.480: E/AndroidRuntime(1246):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-06 00:16:41.480: E/AndroidRuntime(1246): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.android.gcm.demo.app.GcmBroadcastReceiver" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.google.android.gcm.demo.app-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.google.android.gcm.demo.app-1, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
09-06 00:16:41.480: E/AndroidRuntime(1246):     at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:53)
09-06 00:16:41.480: E/AndroidRuntime(1246):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
09-06 00:16:41.480: E/AndroidRuntime(1246):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
09-06 00:16:41.480: E/AndroidRuntime(1246):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2400)
09-06 00:16:41.480: E/AndroidRuntime(1246):     ... 10 more
```

(sorry that i'm not able to post image due to my insufficient of reputation.)

I'm using emulator as below

**Target: Google API Level - 18**

and added Google account to it (which i think is not neccessary, because i'm using android 4.3).

At the server side, i tried to built a WCF service and send a HTTP POST request, and got the following response:

"**STATUS: 200 - OK
id=0:1378440485753994%921c249af9fd7ecd**"

besides, i also tried using GCM testing server at [helmibaraja.com](http://helmibaraja.com/gcm_demo.html), and got the following response

"**{"multicast_id":6425765079749845115,"success":1,"failure":0,"canonical_ids":0,"results":[{"message_id":"0:1378441452317757%921c249af9fd7ecd"}]}**"

so i'm thinking the server side is not a problem.

I'm hoping someone corrected me at the client side, on the emulator setting, or etc...

Btw, i also imported the "**google-play-services_lib**" to my package explorer and added "**gcm.jar**" and "**gcm-src.jar**" to my project's Java Build Path.

Thanks in advance!

**CORRECTION:** the above exception is caused when click on the button in the demo client app.

The following logs show when send GCM from the server.

```
09-06 01:13:51.580: W/BroadcastQueue(274): Unable to launch app com.google.android.gcm.demo.app/10057 for broadcast Intent { act=com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE flg=0x10 pkg=com.google.android.gcm.demo.app (has extras) }: process is bad
09-06 01:13:51.610: W/GTalkService(466): [DataMsgMgr] broadcast intent callback: result=CANCELLED forIntent { act=com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE pkg=com.google.android.gcm.demo.app (has extras) }
```

Comment: Please add your manifest and your broadcast receiver class to the question.

Answer (score 0):

The framework is not able to find the broadcastreceiver. you need to declare that in your manifest file.

inside the receiver tag:

```
<receiver
        android:name="com.google.android.gcm.demo.app.GcmBroadcastReceiver"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
        <intent-filter>
            <!-- Receives the actual messages. -->
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <!-- Receives the registration id. -->
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
            <category android:name="PACKAGE_NAME" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Comment: the exception still there...
I'm wondering what does the following means
"on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.google.android.gcm.demo.app-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.google.android.gcm.demo.app-1, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]"

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Go to Project/Properties/Java Build Path/Order and Export -- Make sure there's a check in front of Android Dependencies and the support library, if you use it.Mark all checkboxes.Click on Apply and clean the project.

Add like this :

```
<receiver
        android:name="com.google.android.gcm.GCMBroadcastReceiver"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />

            <category android:name="com.test.android" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

It should be : `com.google.android.gcm.GCMBroadcastReceiver` and not `.GCMBroadcastReceiver`

This worked for me.Hope this helps.